# Copy an Array of Characters into a Pointer of characters

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, char

I am trying to copy a char[] `array` into a char* `pointer`.

I have 2 datatypes: `CHAR* dst` and `CHAR src[]`

My goal is to perform this operation without using any C++ definitions such as `new or delete`.

As you may understand, this means that I am looking for an operation which I can use that will not increase the size of my compilation.

What I've tried?

```
*src = '\0';
strcpy(dst, src);

strncpy(dst, src, sizeof(src));
```

Basically, I'm stuck, would anyone be able to give me any ideas?

Comment: That's going to be an awfully short copy regardless of `strcpy` or `strncpy` if your first move is setting the first `char` to be a terminating nullchar. You need to know two things: the length of the source string, and the size of the target buffer.

Comment: Can you give some more sample code? Preferably the definitions for `dst` and `src`; what are the initial values?

Comment: @WhozCraig I meant `src[size - 1] = '\0'`. I was in a rush, so I quickly dabbled what I could barely remember from my code, but Alexei answered my question.

Comment: @ilan_portman then you should uptick his answer and check it off please.

Comment: You should refresh your page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have memory allocated for destination in some way, you can't just "copy into pointer" as it does not point to anything.

If you need C way of allocating - [`malloc`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/malloc/) and similar functions are usually used for that.

```
dst = (char*)malloc(strlen(src)+1);
```

You can also point to existing pre-allocated buffer inside your code

```
char[100] buffer;
dst = buffer + 42; // pointing to somewhere in the middle.
```

Some C runtimes allow to also dynamically allocate memory on the stack (which would be ok if you need it just in your current function) like [alloca](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/alloca.3.html).

You need to be careful when copying to not exceed amount of memory available at destination, otherwise you get unpredictable bad results (crashes, program memory corruption, random behavior).

Comment: On top of the answer, thanks for the explanation & the other approach. I'm sure this can help someone else. Cheers.